# Scientific Programming with Ruby

Tags: ruby, math, plot, scientific-computing, algebra

I was doing the mathematical calculations with python or octave because of availability of really nice functions and libraries at hand. But recently I gained interest in ruby and I wonder if there is an equivalent in Ruby to the numpy, scipy in Python for scientific programming. Specifically, I'm looking something that I can draw plots as in matplotlib and do mathematical, algebraic calculations quickly as in numpy and scipy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linear algebra is at the heart of most large-scale scientific computing.  LAPACK is the gold standard for linear algebra libraries, first written in FORTRAN.

There's a port to Ruby [here](http://rubyforge.org/projects/linalg/).  Once you have that, the rest is incidental, but there are also [plotting routines in Ruby](http://scripts.top4download.com/free-plot-math-functions/ruby/).

Comment: I've spent a couple of hours installing it and fighting with legacy fortran dependencies, here are the instructions, hopefully it will save time to someone: http://www.quora.com/Installation-Instructions/How-do-I-install-Ruby-linalg-library-on-Mac

Answer (score 9):

[SciRuby](http://sciruby.com) is working on this. [NMatrix](http://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix) and [Statsample](http://github.com/SciRuby/statsample) are probably the most useful SciRuby gems for linear algebra and statistics, respectively, though you might also find these useful: [distribution](http://github.com/SciRuby/distribution), [minimization](http://github.com/SciRuby/minimization), and [integration](http://github.com/SciRuby/integration).

As far as visualization and plotting goes, check out [Rubyvis](http://rubyvis.rubyforge.org/) (a Ruby port of Protovis). [Nyaplot](http://github.com/domitry/nyaplot) is also coming along nicely.

If you need something more stable than NMatrix, there's always [NArray](http://narray.rubyforge.org/).

I'm also surprised no one has mentioned [Ruby/GSL](http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/). There's also a fork which supports NMatrix over in the [SciRuby github account](http://github.com/SciRuby).

Full disclosure: I'm an admin for SciRuby, but I don't make any money off of it. =)

Comment: Remark: @mohawkjohn (John Woods) has received pat on the shoulder from Matz himself to develop the all-important `NMatrix` library, using Fortran routines for speed.

Answer (score 3):

I compared and gave examples for a number of [different plotting libraries](https://github.com/chrislo/data_visualisation_ruby) that you can use from Ruby. I hope that helps with the second part of your question.